# No Error, but can't input data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code to insert data to Database using MySQL. But when I ran that code using Python, there's no error. But when I checked the Database, the data isn't inserted. Is there anyone who can help me? I would appreciate it. :)

This is the code:

```
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="try")
cursor=db.cursor()

insert="INSERT INTO `try`.`try` (`nomor`, `nama`) VALUES (NULL, 'bismillah')"
cursor.execute(insert)
```

Comment: what does the mysql log say?

Comment: Are those really back-ticks or normal 'single-quotes'?

Comment: @cdarke: In MySQL, [backticks are used to quote identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) instead of the standard double quotes (which are only used to quote literal text strings, even in positions where strings aren't allowed; there's an option to allow double quotes for identifiers, but that forces strings to be single-quoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing a [`COMMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) anywhere. So, if auto-commit is not on, all you've done is create a transaction that, if later committed, will insert this row.

Since you haven't done a `SET AUTOCOMMIT` anywhere, whether auto-commit is on depends on how you created the database. With at least some storage types (in particular, InnoDB), you can change the default at creation time, and, because you often *want* auto-commit disabled with those storage types, your GUI design tool, or the sample code you copied and pasted, or whatever may have done so for you. Also, the server variable that provides the default can itself be set to a different value at server startup/configuration. (See [System Server Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html).)

If you want to make sure that auto-commit is on, just execute `SET autocommit=1` before any other statements.

If you want to find out whether auto-commit is on, execute `SHOW VARIABLES`. (And if it's disabled, you may want to try `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit'` and `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES like 'autocommit'` to see which context you've disabled it in.)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot insert into mysql, there are several ways to solve it:
1: check the log
2: check the structure of your table, maybe it must not be null for `nomor` or other field
3: the last, when insert into mysqldb using program, you need to commit before you close the connection. for here: db.commit()